# Dropdown combo box is not refreshed from the controller after the ajax call

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using bootstrap-multiselect.css and bootstrap-multiselect.js for MultiSelect dropdown
I have a multiselect combo for the dropdown of depots and some depots would be default selected in  the combo. If I change Depot and then Department, the ajax call will call BankHolidaySettings() to populate the bank holidays of changed depot and department. The holidays is populated correctly according to the selected Depot and Department, but the Depot combo box selected depot is not updated from the controller. Here is the code

Controller

```
public IActionResult BankHolidaySettings( int DEPT = 0, int YR = 0, string DEPOTS="")
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID") != null)
            {
                BankHoliday bankHoliday = new BankHoliday();
                BankHoliday hol = new BankHoliday();
                if (DEPT > 0)
                {
                    bankHoliday.DepartmentID = DEPT;
                }

                bankHoliday.Year = (YR == 0) ? DateTime.Today.Year : YR;
                ViewBag.Result = "";
                if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID") != null)
                {
                    

                    var user_depots = _unitOfWork.UserDepotLink.GetUserDepots(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserID") ?? 0);
                    // List of depots to be selected
                    List<string> selectedDepots = new List<string> { "1", "3" };
                    // Create an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> from the locations
                    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = user_depots.Select(depot => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = depot.Value,
                        Text = depot.Text,
                        Selected = selectedDepots.Contains(depot.Value)
                    });
                    hol.UserDepots = selectList;
                   
                    if (DEPT == 0)
                    {
                        DEPT = bankHoliday.DepartmentID = user.DepartmentID;
                    }
                    ViewBag.BankHolidays = _unitOfWork.BankHolidayRepo.GetBankholidaysForDepartment(DEPT, bankHoliday.Year);
                    
                }

                hol.Year = 2023;
                return View(hol);

            }
           
        }
```

View page

```
<select id="dropdownDepot" class="form-control" multiple asp-for="Depots" asp-items="@Model.UserDepots" data-role="select"></select>
<select id="dropdownDepartment" class="form-control" asp-for="DepartmentID" asp-items="@ViewBag.UserDepartments" onchange="FillHolidaysnew()"></select>


<script>
 $('#dropdownDepot').multiselect({
            columns: 2,
            placeholder: 'Select Depot',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            maxHeight: 300,
            search: true
        });
 function FillHolidaysnew() {
        var selectedItem = $("#dropdownDepot").val();
        var departments = $("#dropdownDepartment option:selected").val();
    $(selectedItem).each(function (index, brand) {
            depots = $("#dropdownDepot").val() + ",";
        });
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Employee/BankHolidaySettings",
            data: { DEPT: departments, YR: 2024, DEPOTS: depots },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                // Update a container on the page with the received HTML
                $("#depotholidays").html(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Model

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserDepots { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @Alevel, what is your element which id is  `depotholidays`? For your ajax success function is to update this element's html code with `BankHolidaySettings` view which is filled with `hol` model data.